# Set the value in temp table while checking two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm using SQL Server: I need to update a column(phone number) in temp table based on checking two column values one after another. Here is my current version of code: Basically what it does is, it sets the value of column in the temp table based on where it match the join condition.

```
update r
    set t.phone_number = tb.phone_number
    from #temptable t
    inner join phone_number_records tb 
    on t.id = tb.id
    and 1 = tb.is_this_valid
```

Now I need to check another column value (ready_to_accept_new) in phone_number_records table and update the phone_number field in temp table as per ready_to_accept_new value. If ready_to_accept_new is equal to "1" and "id" of temptable matches with "id" of phone_number_records, i need to set phone_number value in the temptable with the matching record phone_number(in phone_number_records table). If there are no matching records on this criteria, we need to update the temp table record as previous.( from matching is_this_valid column value "1" record).

Can someone please let me know how to solve this one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is likely that `MERGE` will make your life easier. If you add few rows with sample data and what result you expect there is a good chance that somebody will write an answer. Your current description of the logic is difficult to understand without example.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way is to join to your table twice.
Use a left join for the per ready_to_accept_new value join and then use a case statement to see if this exists.
IE:

```
update r
set t.phone_number = 
 CASE 
 WHEN tb_1.id IS NOT NULL THEN tb_1.phone_number 
 ELSE tb.phone_number 
 END 
from #temptable t
inner join phone_number_records tb 
on t.id = tb.id
and 1 = tb.is_this_valid
left join phone_number_records tb_1
on t.id = tb.id
and 1 = tb.per ready_to_accept_new value
```

apologies for the formatting!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer supplied by John, it can be done with IF..ELSE block

```
if exists(select * from #temptable t
        inner join phone_number_records tb 
        on t.id = tb.id
        and 1 = tb.ready_to_accept_new )

    update r
    set t.phone_number = tb.phone_number
    from #temptable t
    inner join phone_number_records tb 
    on t.id = tb.id
    and 1 = tb.ready_to_accept_new 

else

    update r
    set t.phone_number = tb.phone_number
    from #temptable t
    inner join phone_number_records tb 
    on t.id = tb.id
    and 1 = tb.is_this_valid
```